# docker command not working for specific user

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to execute the "docker run hello-world" command for two different users. It works fine for the "ec2-user"

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-83 ~]$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

But not for the "gitlab-runner" user

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-83 ~]$ sudo docker run hello-world --user=gitlab-runner
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"--user=gitlab-runner\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

What could be the reason?

$PATH for user gitlab-runner

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-83 ~]$ echo $PATH --user=gitlab-runner
>   /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
>   --user=gitlab-runner [ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-83 ~]$ whereis docker docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
>   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-83 ~]$

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run:

```sh
sudo docker run \
  hello-world \           # image name
  --user=gitlab-runner    # command to run inside the container
```

If you have any options to `docker run` they need to be *before* the image name

```sh
sudo docker run \
  --user=gitlab-runner \  # set the user based off the container's /etc/passwd
  hello-world             # image name
                          # running the default command
```